# Input text behaves stranges with edittext android

Tags: android

for some reason android doesn't put the text input above the 'keyboard'. Because of this you can't see what your typing. I have tried various things but without result does anyway have clue?

this is the code:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/comment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Please include your whole layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your application Manifest this property to each activity where this problem occurs:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```